# Why is it faster to iterate in nested loops, and why does my benchmarking data have distinct bands of outliers?

Tags: r, performance, loops, benchmarking

I benchmarked some simple R code that uses a loop to repeatedly call a function that generates some random numbers.  I had previously noticed that if I loop for 10000 iterations, its much, much slower than if I loop for 1000 iterations, and then wrap that loop in another loop of 10 iterations.  My first question is, why is it slower to run one loop many times than it is to run it the same number of times but in nested loops?

Anyway, I wanted to see what the optimal number of iterations in the inner loop are, so I tested it with various values and plotted the results.  Somewhere around 300 iterations in the inner loop looks optimal, but the scatter of the data is pretty interesting.  There are three distinct 'trend bands'.  I'd really like to know what causes this behaviour if anyone can shed any light on it.

Here is the code I used for benchmarking.

```
n_step <- c(50:3000)
benchmark1<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=12,nrow=0))
for (n in n_step){
  start_time<-Sys.time()
  best_chr<-generate_data(n)[1,]
  end_time<-Sys.time()
  run_time <- end_time - start_time
  measure <- data.frame(n, run_time, time_per_chr_roll = run_time/n) 
  measure <- cbind(best_chr, measure)
  benchmark1 <- rbind(benchmark1, measure)
  }
   
plot(benchmark1$n,benchmark1$time_per_chr_roll)
```

[image: Plot of iterations in loop (x axis) vs time per iteration (y axis)]

edit: adding code for generate_data() and related functions.

```
roll_stats<-function(){
stat<-floor(runif(3,min=1,max=7))
stat=sum(stat)
return(stat)
}

generate_stats<-function(){
  stats<-c(1:6)
  for (i in c(1:6)){
    stats[i]<-roll_stats()
  }
  return(stats)
}

generate_data<-function(n){
stat_data<-data.frame()
for (i in c(1:n)){
  stats<-generate_stats()
stat_data<-rbind(stat_data,stats)
}
colnames(stat_data)<-c("roll1","roll2","roll3","roll4","roll5","roll6")
stat_data<-stat_data %>%
  mutate(sum = roll1+roll2+roll3+roll4+roll5+roll6, average = sum/6)
stat_data$count.18<-apply(stat_data,1,function(x) length(which(x==18)))
stat_data<-stat_data[order(-stat_data$sum,-stat_data$count.18),]
#write.csv(stat_data,file=paste0(n," 3d6 x6 ", floor(runif(1,min=1,max=99999999999)),".csv"))
return(stat_data)
}
```

Comment: Please share a `generate_data` function that recreates the problem. If I use a function that does nothing, I get a different result with no evidence of multiple bands.

Comment: That's interesting @AndrewChisholm , maybe this is a feature of my functions.  It does occur to me that since my y-axis value is an average over the x-axis value (n) this will probably repress outliers as n increases.

Comment: Also need `generate_stats`.

Comment: It's there too, along with the roll_stats function that it calls

Comment: I don't see the trend banks either. `stat_data<-rbind(stat_data, stats)` will be burning lots of time. `bind_rows` is often faster. You can also preallocate `stat_data` and update rows.

Comment: I'm seeing it consistently on my computer, so I'm wondering if its something about my hardware.  My hypothesis is that for whatever reason there is occasionally a glitch that makes a single iteration of the loop take much longer than average.  I speculate that it happens at regular intervals, which gives large outliers at low values of n, and several bands of lesser outliers at higher values of n, because the average over n is more effected at lower values of n.  At higher values, the 'glitch' can occur more than once in the loop, but has a reduced effect on the average overall.